# MySQL write empty json in column of JSON type

Tags: mysql

How to override a column of JSON type that has value = NULL to empty json, {}?

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `column_json` = JSON_SET(NULL, '{}', '{}')
WHERE
    `condition` = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simply check for `IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause, and then set the JSON column to string `{}`. MySQL should be able to implicitly typecast the string literal (which is also a valid JSON literal) to JSON:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `column_json` = '{}'
WHERE
    `condition` = 1 
     AND `column_json` IS NULL
```

Comment: And this should work because a string literal should also be a valid JSON literal.

Comment: Hey Madhur... congratulations for earning the mysql gold badge!